# Default control collection

Tags: c#, winforms, collections, controls

When I create & add a control to my `WinForm` using the designer, is my control automatically added to a collection with all the others somewhere ?

Let's say there are like 20 `TextBox` and I need to clear them all at the same time without calling it like so :

```
txtbox1.Clear();
txtbox2.Clear();
txtbox3.Clear();
...
```

I know I should have created manually each control without the designer and add them in a collection but it's too late for that now. So any idea if I can access the whole group of controls ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
private void ClearTextBoxes()
{
 Action<Control.ControlCollection> func = null;

 func = (controls) =>
     {
         foreach (Control control in controls)
             if (control is TextBox)
                 (control as TextBox).Clear();
             else
                 func(control.Controls);
     };

 func(Controls);
}
```

Comment: Exaclty what I just found out. Although your version is a bit too complicated. But thanks exactly the logic I need

Answer (score 0):

Oh I actually found out how to do this just after I wrote my question.
I can use a `foreach loop` on `this.controls`.
Then I test if the control is a `TextBox`.

```
foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
{
  if (x is TextBox)
  {
    ((TextBox)x).Text = String.Empty;
  }   
}
```

Comment: Note that this will fail on containers: there you will need to dig deeper, like Garry did